# How to fix/properly configure conda 4.7 shell to use 'conda active' on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I run Ubuntu 18.04.

I downloaded and ran the Pyhon 3.7 64Bit(x86) version of [Anaconda 2019.10 install .sh](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-18-04).

In my fresh Anaconda installation the following run flawless

```
conda info
conda list
conda init
conda create
conda env list
```

My Problem:
`conda activate` fails with

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I'm confused by this message. The thing is that I have already initialized my shell in the installation process.

Therefore `conda init bash` returns `No action taken.`

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix in [Anaconda's official installation guide's troubleshooting list](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#cannot-get-conda-to-run-after-installing).

My takeaway from this situation is to stick to the official documentation.

Comment: Hmm, that documentation seems outdated, unfortunately. It may work, but it can result in the **base** env leaking into other envs that have the same Python version, which was the whole reason why the team stopped recommending manipulating `PATH` since Conda v.4.4 and introduced `conda init`. I'd keep trying to get `conda init` working instead. Perhaps clean out everything Conda-related in the `.bashrc` and run `conda init` again.

Comment: @merv, thanks for the advice to use ```conda init```! I'm still riddled about where that error came from and how it disappeared, but it helped me familiarize with and feel more comfortable using Anaconda, now that everything is working.